# "Механика" слайдера

Tags: jquery

Вопрос по механике слайдера..
Никак не могу допереть, как **нормально** сделать движение слайдера.

Вот наброски, на как можете наблюдать - они коряво работают.

```js
////////////////////////////////
var i;
for(i=1;i<10+1;i++){$('.s-content-wrap').append('<div class="s-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide '+i+'"></div>');};
sliderLoad();
////////////////////////////////
function sliderLoad() {
 var sliderWidth = $('.slider .s-content').width();
 $('.slider').each(function(){
   var sliderWrap = $(this).find('.s-content-wrap');
   var sliderItemLen = $(this).find('.s-item').length;
   $(this).find('.s-item').width(sliderWidth);
    $(this).find('.s-content-wrap').width(sliderWidth*sliderItemLen).css('left',-sliderWidth);
    $(this).find('.s-item:last-child').prependTo(sliderWrap);
        
    $('.s--prev').on('click',function(){
      SliderPrev();
    });
    $('.s--next').on('click',function(){
      SliderNext();
    });

    function SliderPrev() {
     var sliderItemLast = $(this).find('.s-item:last-child');
     sliderWrap.animate({
       'margin-left': sliderWidth
      }, 1500, function(){
       sliderItemLast.prependTo($(this).find('.s-content-wrap'));
        sliderWrap.css('margin-left','0');
      });
    }
    
    function SliderNext() {
     var sliderItemFirst = $(this).find('.s-item:first-child');
     sliderWrap.animate({
       'margin-left': -sliderWidth
      }, 1500, function(){
       sliderItemFirst.appendTo($(this).find('.s-content-wrap'));
        sliderWrap.css('margin-left','0');
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
img {border: 0;}

.slider {display: block; width: 100%; height: 250px; position: relative;}
.s-content {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
.s-content-wrap {display: block; height: 100%; position: relative;}
.s-content-wrap::after {content: ''; display: block; clear: both;}
.s-item {display: inline-block; float: left; height: 100%;}
.s-item img {width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;}

.s-button {display: block; width: 32px; height: 32px; text-align: center; line-height: 32px; font-size: 21px; background: #333; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 16px); z-index: 2;}
.s-button.s--prev {left: 0;}
.s-button.s--next {left: calc(100% - 32px);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!----------------------------------->
<div class="slider">
  <div class="s-button s--prev">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="s-content">
    <div class="s-content-wrap">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="s-button s--next">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Важно**, код должен работать "отдельно" с каждым слайдером на странице. В "наброске" данный момент учтён.

Comment: *...как **нормально** сделать движение слайдера...* - поясните подробнее, что хотите получить в результате

Comment: @Alex, анимацию перелистывания к слайдам. (я даже код добавил.. Чаще замечаю что люди игнорируют часть информации -_-)

Comment: может быть кто-то и игнорирует, Вам виднее. Вы не ответили на вопрос, что в Вашем понимании есть **нормально** ? более плавно, без подергиваний или что-то еще ? что значит **они коряво работают** ?

Comment: @Alex, нажмите на стрелку слайдера, в любую сторону, вы увидите что слайд вернётся обратно на тот с которого уходил. В данном случае `Slide 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Незнаю зачем на марджинах сделал, вот как бы я реализовал:

```js
var i;
for(i=1;i<2+1;i++){
    $('.s-content-wrap').append('<div class="s-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide '+i+'"></div>');
}

class Slider {

    constructor(settings = {}) {

        this.selector = settings.selector !== undefined 
            ? settings.selector 
            : '.slider';

        this.wrapper_selector = settings.wrapper_selector !== undefined 
            ? settings.wrapper_selector 
            : '.s-content-wrap';

        this.slide_selector = settings.slide_selector !== undefined 
            ? settings.slide_selector 
            : '.s-item';

        this.prev_selector = settings.prev_selector !== undefined 
            ? settings.prev_selector 
            : '.s--prev';

        this.next_selector = settings.next_selector !== undefined 
            ? settings.next_selector 
            : '.s--next';

        this.sliderDom = document.querySelector(this.selector);
        if (this.sliderDom !== null) {
            this.init();
        }

    }

    init() {

        this.slidesWrapper = this.sliderDom.querySelector(this.wrapper_selector);
        this.slides = this.slidesWrapper.querySelectorAll(this.slide_selector);

        this.prev = this.sliderDom.querySelector(this.prev_selector);
        this.next = this.sliderDom.querySelector(this.next_selector);

        this.slideWidth = this.sliderDom.offsetWidth;

        var width = this.slideWidth * (this.slides.length + 2);

        this.slidesWrapper.style.width = width + 'px';
        
        this.slides.forEach(function(el){
            el.style.width = this.slideWidth + 'px';
        }.bind(this));

        this.slidesWrapper.insertBefore(this.slides[this.slides.length - 1], this.slides[0]);
        this.slidesWrapper.style.left = - this.sliderDom.offsetWidth + 'px';

        this.prev.addEventListener('click', this.prevSlide.bind(this));
        this.next.addEventListener('click', this.nextSlide.bind(this));

    }

    prevSlide() {

        this.slides = this.slidesWrapper.querySelectorAll(this.slide_selector);

        var last = this.slides[this.slides.length - 1];

        var new_last = last.cloneNode(true);

        this.slidesWrapper.insertBefore(new_last, this.slides[0]);
        
        var animation = new_last.animate([
            {width: '0'},
            {width: this.slideWidth + 'px'}
        ], 500);

        animation.addEventListener('finish', function() {
            new_last.style.width = this.slideWidth + 'px';
            last.parentNode.removeChild(last);
        });

    }

    nextSlide() {

        this.slides = this.slidesWrapper.querySelectorAll(this.slide_selector);

        var first = this.slides[0];

        this.slidesWrapper.insertBefore(first, this.slides[this.slides.length]);

        var animation = this.slidesWrapper.animate([
            {paddingLeft: this.slideWidth + 'px'},
            {paddingLeft: '0'}
        ], 500);

    }

}

var slider = new Slider({
    selector: ".slider"
});
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
img {border: 0;}

.slider {display: block; width: 100%; height: 250px; position: relative;}
.s-content {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
.s-content-wrap {display: block; height: 100%; position: relative;}
.s-content-wrap::after {content: ''; display: block; clear: both;}
.s-item {display: inline-block; float: left; height: 100%;}
.s-item img {width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;}

.s-button {display: block; width: 32px; height: 32px; text-align: center; line-height: 32px; font-size: 21px; background: #333; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 16px); z-index: 2;}
.s-button.s--prev {left: 0;}
.s-button.s--next {left: calc(100% - 32px);}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="slider">
        <div class="s-button s--prev">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="s-content">
            <div class="s-content-wrap">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="s-button s--next">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

А вообще, лучше не писать велосипед - а использовать готовые библиотеки, например Slick-slider. 
З.Ы. не уверен что будет корректно работать, с кол-вом слайдов меньше 3-х

Comment: Поправил код - работает корректно и с 2-мя слайдами